# SystemClock.sleep() vs. Thread.sleep() while waiting for a semaphore loop

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

In order to synchronize/queue access to a shared resource, I am about to use a [Semaphore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), aided by a wait loop.

In order not to run into CPU pegging, I would like to `sleep()` a little bit inside that `while` loop.

I searched the http://developer.android.com reference and found two such sleep() functions and I am confused as to which one fits which scenario:

1. [Thread.sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29)
2. [SystemClock.sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep%28long%29)

Which one better suits the case I described and why?

Comment: `SystemClock.sleep()` runs in UI thread... I think.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub, You are wrong. It is not mentioned on the docs about that it runs on UI Thread. This is misleading.

Comment: @FredrickGauss Well It's for 4 years ago and I WAS going wrong... So yes, only if called from the non-UI thread.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, do you really need a wait loop? You can typically solve your problems using proper notifications, i.e. having an Object, calling `wait()` and `notify()` on it or other means (like a blocking queue, or `Semaphore.acquire()` in your case).

That said, if you really want a polling loop (which you really shouldn't do unless you have to), I'd stick with `Thread.sleep()`. There's not much of a difference, as the documentation says, except that you have the option to interrupt a `Thread.sleep()`. Don't rid yourself the option to do so.

Note that in case of `Thread.sleep()`, you're going to have to catch that exception - if you're extremely lazy, you'll probably stick with `SystemClock.sleep()`.

Comment: Thanks for this great and timely clarification. I just discovered that `Semaphore.acquire()` may be the best option.

Comment: If you're using wait() you need to do so in a loop. wait() can return before the call to notify(). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait() for correct usage.

"Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks: When Threads Unravel" covers this topic well.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is:

Thread.sleep(n) could be interrupted within a call like AsyncTask by using asyncTask.cancel(true)

SystemClock.sleep(n) seems to ignore any interrupted command, thus it could be a risk of memory leak when you use it similar like here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-sample/src/main/java/com/example/leakcanary/MainActivity.java

Comment: They're not related. That example just uses a sleep in order to give you time to rotate the screen, which causes a leak.